# traer un dato de un select en procedimiento almacenado

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedure

haciendo un trabajo necesito traer un id que es la ultima primary key generada en una tabla y mostrarla en un textbox de windows form mediante un procedimiento almacenado, todo por medio de entity framework

````
este es el procedimiento almacenado
```
create procedure idMax
as
begin
  select max (Codigo) from Articulo
end
go
````

aqui el intento de metodo para llamar al procedimiento almacenado, pero me arroja que no se puede transformar de tipo int a int

```
public idMax()
        {
            int id;
            using (BodegaManagementEntities db = new BodegaManagementEntities())
            {
               return id= db.idMax(); 
            }
        }
```

este es el error
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   CS0029  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<int?>' en 'int'  bodega4

de antemano, muuchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tú dices:

> no se puede transformar de tipo int a int

Pero esto no es el error que aparece, el cual dice que puede pasar de `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<int?>` en `int`

Es decir tu función idMax retorna un [ObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectresult?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) que tiene elementos del tipo `int?` (int nulleable) que son distintos a los `int` de toda la vida. Donde los primeros pueden ser nulos, en cambio los `int` simples nunca pueden ser nulos

Según la documentación ObjectResult implementa `IEnumerable`, así que supondré que te devuelve una lista, por lo que tu código debería ser así

```
public int idMax()
{
   using (BodegaManagementEntities db = new BodegaManagementEntities())
   {
     return db.idMax()?.FirstOrDefault()??0; //Devuelve cero en caso de ser nulo, tú puedes poner cualquier valor que consideres adecuado como default
   }
}
```